# Python error: This method is only available to the class, not on instances

Tags: python, django, view

I am working on a Django application and have defined the line below in my urls.py

```
path('organizations/', views.OrganizationListView().as_view(), name='organizations'),
```

When I run my server, I get the error below

```
lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 11, in __get__
    raise AttributeError("This method is available only on the class, not on instances.")
AttributeError: This method is available only on the class, not on instances.
```

I understand that this must be because of the difference in calling a method on object vs class but not sure exactly what is causing it and how to resolve.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're instantiating the class here, which you shouldn't. It should be:

```
path('organizations/', views.OrganizationListView.as_view(), name='organizations'),
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm following the steps suggested here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views
Under "URL Mapping" and I assume this would be working. So I must be missing something in my code.

Comment: Yes. That page shows the same as my code, not yours.

Comment: @Jorjani Just in case you missed it, he removed the parentheses after OrganizationListView. Not immediately obvious what the change was to me.